# Docker: How to add backports to sources.list via Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, docker, debian, dockerfile, debian-jessie

I need to install `ffmeg` on debian jessie via Dockerfile.

Debian recommends to use backports. But how do I do this in my Dockerfile?

Add

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main non-free
```

to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

This is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:4.8-slim

COPY . /

## How to add backports to list ???

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg && ffmpeg -i

RUN (cd programs/server && npm install --silent)
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

Comment: Related: [How to add repository from shell in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-add-repository-from-shell-in-debian)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it by adding below

```
RUN printf "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
```

Comment: doing this with `docker exec -it -u root ...` gives me `Permission denied`

Answer (score 6):

Looking for the same issue I have seen that Debian provides Docker images for `backport` versions. So you do not need to do that yourself. For instance you can have a `jessie backports` Dockerfile using `FROM debian:jessie-backports` command.

By looking at what [one of the Debian official backport files do](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/223b1234e2bcd3248b7e8feb86b8aedd00e5487f/jessie/backports/Dockerfile) to have the backport version it boils down to something similar to what Tarun's asnwer, using the base distribution then appending the backports to a specific `backports.list`, i.e.:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
```

Answer (score 5):

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, `>>` is required when appending to sources.list.

```
RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Other answers create a new flie in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which is OK, but the original question refers to appending to `sources.list`.  Use `>>` to append to a file.

Comment: How to add multiple entry in the list.